# Django remote MySQL connection refused 1045

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Getting this error:

```
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'db_user'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (using password: YES)")
```

I have commented out the following line in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on the db server:

```
 #bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

I have granted `db_user` permission to access from the remote IP:

```
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'db_user'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX';
> flush privileges;
```

But I keep the getting the error. I've configured remote db's in this way before, stumped as to why its not working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think the issue is more with connecting to mysql, than the user having access. can you connect to mysql from command line using these settings ? `mysql -u db_user -h 'xxx.xxx.xxx' -p` ?

Comment: the bind address wasn't the problem. if mysql wasn't listening on the proper ip, then it'd have been connection refused or timed out. access denied means a connection WAS established, but with the wrong credentials. the `x.x.x.x` in the grant query has to be the IP your client code is connecting FROM. make sure there's no proxies/nat gateways intercepting your connection.

Comment: `mysql -u db_user -h 'xxx.xxx.xxx' -p` returns the same error. The IP in the grant query was for the remote server that was trying to access the db.